# Stepper using Variables from Binding Structs Crashes View?

Tags: swift, struct, binding, stepper

I am passing an object between views using @Binding from the previous view. The struct is designed as such:

```
struct Topping: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    var amount: Int
    let id = UUID()
}
// Ex. Topping(name: "Cheese", price: 3.00, amount: 0)

struct ToppingList: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    var list: [Topping]
    var id: String {
        name+"menu\(menu.indices)"
    }
}
// Ex. ToppingList(name: "Cheeses", menu: [Topping(...), Topping(...)])

struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let size: [String]
    let image: String
    let price: [Double]
    var toppings: [ToppingList]
    var id: String {
        "_"+name
    }
}
// Ex. MenuItem(...toppings: [Topping(name: "Cheese", price: 3.00, amount: 0), Topping(name: "Pepperoni", price: 3.00, amount: 0)])
```

I pass the list of toppings to the view, and with a stepper hope to increment or decrement the amount of toppings (per unique topping). The problem that arises is when this happens, the view crashes to my home page.

The code for the views is separated into 2 - one for displaying the rows of steppers in a form, and the child view - for the individual rows.

```
// This view is the main view, 
struct ToppingCategoryView: View {

@Binding var menuItem: MenuItem
// Pretend this is the MenuItem passed:
// MenuItem(...toppings: ToppingList(name: "Cheeses", list: [Topping(name: "Mozza", price: 3.00, amount: 0), Topping(name: "Parmesan", price: 3.00, amount: 0)]))

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            ForEach($menuItem.toppings) { $menu in
                Section (menu.name){
                    ExtraToppingsView(toppingsList: $menu.list)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following view is where the stepper and @Binding variable is. I wish to increase the amount of toppings. Doing so, dismisses the view, but still increases the variable. If I load the view again, it displays correctly. Not sure why the view is dismissed. No error messages or warnings I could reproduce or find.

```
struct ExtraToppingsView: View {

@Binding var toppingsList: [Topping]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach($toppingsList) { $topping in
            Stepper {
                Text("\(topping.amount)")
            } onIncrement: {
                topping.amount += 1
                if topping.amount >= 4 { topping.amount = 3 }
            } onDecrement: {
                topping.amount -= 1
                if topping.amount <= -1 { topping.amount = 0 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than including stuff like "Pretend this is the MenuItem passed:", can you create a `ContentView` that actually passes the parameters that you want -- I think with that, it would be a [mre] that someone could copy and paste into Xcode and run -- that's what we need to be able to test this out.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was trying to condense my code into a small example without pasting my entire project. Anywho, I found a solution, not sure why it works though. I've posted it as an answer. @jnpdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is, it seems to be some kind of bug or something else I am not aware of.

It relates to using NESTED navigation links.

To fix this, I simply add `.isDetailLink(False)` to EVERY NavigationLink in the project. This fixed the issue.